# Настройка Cron, FreeBSD

Tags: cron, freebsd

Здравствуйте.
Возникли проблемы с Cron в FreeBSD. Cron не хочет запускать PHP скрипты.
Содержимое файла /etc/crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bashPATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/binexport PATH#minute hour    mday    month   wday    who command*/1 *   *   *   *   root    /usr/local/www/apache22/data/mysite.ru/cron/offers.php
```

Файл offers.php имет права 0777.

Для проверки в начале файла стоит:

```
mail('myemail@email.ua', 'cron - offers', 'date' );
```

В файл логов идет:

```
Apr 15 10:30:15 spendhunters newsyslog[970]: logfile first createdApr 15 10:30:38 spendhunters /usr/sbin/cron[1473]: (*system*) PARSE (bad minute)Apr 15 10:30:38 spendhunters /usr/sbin/cron[1473]: (*system*) PARSE (bad minute)Apr 15 10:31:00 spendhunters /usr/sbin/cron[1551]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/mysite.ru/cron/offers.php)Apr 15 10:32:00 spendhunters /usr/sbin/cron[1567]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/mysite.ru/cron/offers.php)Apr 15 10:33:00 spendhunters /usr/sbin/cron[1590]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/mysite.ru/cron/offers.php)Apr 15 10:34:00 spendhunters /usr/sbin/cron[1595]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/mysite.ru/cron/offers.php)Apr 15 10:35:00 spendhunters /usr/sbin/cron[1599]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/mysite.ru/cron/offers.php)Apr 15 10:36:00 spendhunters /usr/sbin/cron[1609]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/mysite.ru/cron/offers.php)Apr 15 10:37:00 spendhunters /usr/sbin/cron[1623]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/mysite.ru/cron/offers.php)
```

Как можно настроить работу Cron в FreeBSD ?
Спасибо.

Comment: Не очень понял а в чем проблема?

Comment: Cron не запускает скрыпты

Comment: По преведенному вами логу он его запускает, каждую минуту , не понимаю что вам не нравиться то что вам письмо не отправляется ? Причина скорее не вкроне, попробуйте другое действие в скрипте например date >> /tmp/date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы укажите крону, чем запускать этот файл. Крон ничего про расширения файлов не знает. Надо примерно так:

```
# содержимое /etc/crontab 

* * * * * root php-cli /usr/local/www/apache22/data/mysite.ru/cron/offers.php
```